# Truncate string when it is too long

Tags: ruby, string

I have two strings:

```
short_string = "hello world"
long_string = "this is a very long long long .... string" # suppose more than 10000 chars
```

I want to change the default behavior of `print` to:

```
puts short_string
# => "hello world"
puts long_string
# => "this is a very long long....."
```

The `long_string` is only partially printed. I tried to change `String#to_s`, but it didn't work. Does anyone know how to do it like this?

**updated**

Actually i wanna it works smoothly, that means the following cases also work fine:

```
> puts very_long_str
> puts [very_long_str]
> puts {:a => very_long_str}
```

So i think the behavior belongs to String.

Thanks all anyway.

Answer (score 24):

First of all, you need a method to `truncate` a string, either something like:

```
def truncate(string, max)
  string.length > max ? "#{string[0...max]}..." : string
end
```

Or by extending `String`: (it's not recommended to alter core classes, though)

```
class String
  def truncate(max)
    length > max ? "#{self[0...max]}..." : self
  end
end
```

Now you can call `truncate` when printing the string:

```
puts "short string".truncate
#=> short string

puts "a very, very, very, very long string".truncate
#=> a very, very, very, ...
```

Or you could just define your own `puts`:

```
def puts(string)
  super(string.truncate(20))
end

puts "short string"
#=> short string

puts "a very, very, very, very long string"
#=> a very, very, very, ...
```

Note that [`Kernel#puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) takes a variable number of arguments, you might want to change your `puts` method accordingly.

Comment: If the string is nearly at max, then the ellipsis will put it over. You need something like: `string.length > max ? "#{string[0...(max-3)]}..." : string`, maybe

Comment: Can also use the elipsis character (…) instead of three .s to save 2 more chars so you can retain as much info as possible

Answer (score 15):

This is how [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) does it in their [String#truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate) method as a [monkey-patch](http://www.runtime-era.com/2012/12/reopen-and-modify-ruby-classes-monkey.html):

```
class String
  def truncate(truncate_at, options = {})
    return dup unless length > truncate_at

    options[:omission] ||= '...'
    length_with_room_for_omission = truncate_at - options[:omission].length
    stop = if options[:separator]
      rindex(options[:separator], length_with_room_for_omission) || 
        length_with_room_for_omission
      else
        length_with_room_for_omission
      end

    "#{self[0...stop]}#{options[:omission]}"
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like this

```
'And they found that many people were sleeping better.'.truncate(25, omission: '... (continued)')
# => "And they f... (continued)"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a wrapper around `puts` that handles truncation for you:

```
def pleasant(string, length = 32)
  raise 'Pleasant: Length should be greater than 3' unless length > 3

  truncated_string = string.to_s
  if truncated_string.length > length
    truncated_string = truncated_string[0...(length - 3)]
    truncated_string += '...'
  end

  puts truncated_string
  truncated_string
end
```

Comment: It returns `nil` which makes it a little harder to test.  It should probably just return a truncated string.

Comment: Updated answer to return the truncated string, as @vgoff suggested.

Comment: You missed an underscore though: `truncated_string`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use this syntax:

```
"mystring"[0..MAX_LENGTH]

[5] pry(main)> "hello world"[0..10]
=> "hello world"
[6] pry(main)> "hello world why"[0..10]
=> "hello world"
[7] pry(main)> "hello"[0..10]
=> "hello"
```

There's no need to check if it actually exceed the maximum length.

Answer (score 2):

**Truncate naturally**

I want to propose a solution that truncates naturally. I fell in love with the [String#truncate method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate) offered by [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/). It was already mentioned by @Oto Brglez above. Unfortunately I couldn't rewrite it for pure ruby. So I wrote this function.

```
def truncate(content, max)    
    if content.length > max
        truncated = ""
        collector = ""
        content = content.split(" ")
        content.each do |word|
            word = word + " " 
            collector << word
            truncated << word if collector.length < max
        end
        truncated = truncated.strip.chomp(",").concat("...")
    else
        truncated = content
    end
    return truncated
end
```

**Example**

- Test: I am a sample phrase to show the result of this function.
- NOT: I am a sample phrase to show the result of th...
- BUT: I am a sample phrase to show the result of...

Note: I'm open for improvements because I'm convinced that there is a shorter solution possible.