# How to truncate a SHA1 hashed string into a 32 bit string

Tags: ruby, encryption, sha1, truncate, truncation

I want to create a 32 bit string that I can use as encryption key. This string/key should be derived from a plain text string, e.g.:

```
'I am a string'
```

My approach would first be to hash it:

```
hashed_string = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('I am a string') # => 'bd82fb0e81ee9f15f5929e0564093bc9f8015f1d'
```

And then to use just the first 32 characters:

```
hashed_string[0..31] # => 'bd82fb0e81ee9f15f5929e0564093bc9'
```

However, I feel there must be a better approach, and I'm not sure if I risk the possibility of 2 input strings yielding similar keys.

What would be a better approach? I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046970/truncate-string-when-it-is-too-long) that touches on truncation, but can't find an answer that appeals to me there.

Comment: The gem [pbkdf2](https://github.com/emerose/pbkdf2-ruby) can be useful in your case - as typically one uses such function to derive keys from a passphrase

Comment: You seem to have some confusion about bits vs. bytes. An SHA1 hash is 160 bits. `hexdigest` returns the [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) representation of those bits. Each hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits, so when you take the first 32 characters, you're getting 32 × 4 = 128 bits. At any rate, yes, there is most certainly a better approach—but first we must know what problem you're trying to solve. You want to generate an "encryption key," but for what purpose? What are you encrypting and how are you encrypting it? Why 32 bits (*very* short for an encryption key)?

Comment: How about changing the question? `32 bit string` and `32 characters length string` are two different things.

Comment: Also, whatever you do with your original string, it won't change the fact that it's a weak password. It has already less than 32 bits of entropy. See https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a string with 32 bits out of your (weak) password :

```
Digest::SHA1.digest('I am a string').unpack('B32').first
#=> "10111101100000101111101100001110"
```

The same amount of information can also be displayed with 8 hexadecimal digits :

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('I am a string')[0,8]
#=> "bd82fb0e"
```

or 4 ascii chars :

```
Digest::SHA1.digest('I am a string')[0,4]
#=> "\xBD\x82\xFB\x0E"
```